I am not able to Overriding django model
I have a django model that has multiple fields
class data(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pj = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    explain = models.TextField(max_length=50, null=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name=f"new {self.name}"
        super(data, self).save(*args, **kwargs)



when  i save the data model the name is not getting changed to "new name" it is getting saved as "name"
I want the new naming convention to reflect.

What did you create the data model object from? There is no problem when I create it through Admin.

use just super(). and check you provide update_fields.
if update_fields is not None and name is not in update_fields, name change not save.
    def save(self, update_fields, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'{update_fields=}')
        self.name=f"new {self.name}"
        super().save(update_fields, *args, **kwargs)

